# How to clear the server cache in iis

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I've got a asp.net web site on windows with rather over the top server side caching of files that never change.  Unsurprisingly the files have changed.  How do I reset the server side cache?  I've see lots of how to do it in code but I don't want to add a new page that will clear the cache unless I have too.  An IISreset or a box reset will clear the cache but that's rather drastic. Will an application pool recycle? The app pools are set to terminate after idle time out, that'll probably happen overnight will that clear the cache?

code is:

```
using WebApi.OutputCache.V2;

namespace Foo.Web.API.Controllers
{
    public class BarController :  ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [CacheOutput ServerTimeSpan = 31536000)]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string organisationId, string file)
        {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both clear the cache.
Recycling an App Pool is just less drastic, as it continues to process already received requests and cycles after that. This can be done under load - never had issues with it.

Comment: Sure but you lose session state which my site needs, if the idle shut down clears it I'll try that.  If it does it really calls into question why the server cache was set to a year.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a reason for _any_ cache to have a timeout of a year, I think.

Comment: well cache cleared out overnight after idle shutdown.  Thanks

Comment: Resetting the app pool doesn't work for me. IIS still serves old cshtml pages.

Answer (score 13):

I had to delete the files here. This is all that worked for me.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I believe files are added to these folders only when you are developing and debugging ASP.NET application locally. When you are just hosting ASP.NET website on IIS, no files are added to these folders.

Comment: @Sagar The 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' locations contain compiled intermediate assemblies for .aspx files and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Mysterious caching issue resolved by saving current IIS state and restoring saved state using appcmd utility.

Here's PowerShell script that accomplishes task: (run as admin)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.  Could you by chance edit it to contain textual code, instead of a screenshot?